# Map view getting shrunk in Dynamic table view cell

Tags: swift, dynamic, maps, tableview

In a swift iOS app, I have a tableView in viewController with 2 prototype cells. One cell has two text boxes (Cell) and other cell has one UIview (mapView in MapCell) in which I have to display a google map view with some location markers. I have set leading,trailling , top and bottom constraints for all the things in the cell. Also, included following for dynamic cells.

```
chatMessagesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
chatMessagesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

First cell gets dynamic height depending upon content size, however MapCell is shrunken, tried a lot of things and nothing is helping, please suggest what can I do more. Here is a related code and tableview cell image.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCell

googleMapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:self.tripLocation.latitude, longitude: self.tripLocation.longitude, zoom: 15)

 googleMapView.animate(to: camera)
 cell.mapView.addSubview(googleMapView)
 cell.mapView.sizeToFit()
 cell.updateConstraints()
 cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

[image: Click here for Image of table View]

One more problem is when I scroll down the table, the next cells gets messed up with the constraints , for ex, text alignment! Please help me solve this. I am reading lot of tutorials on constraints and layout, however nothing is really working out!

Comment: Please check your constraints properly. This is the constraints problem. Don't use fix height of the constraints.

Comment: Cell with mapView isn't dynamic, right? Why don't you make it fix sized?

Comment: @ please use this method cell.setNeedsLayout()...i think it would be work.if your constraints is proper.

Comment: Making that cell fixed size worked solved the issue temporarily!! Thanks all